# Distribute six identical items to four different people.

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many way can 6 identical items be given to 4 different people?

I tried labeling all the cookies with letters A-F. And each individual with numbers 1-4.
$$
A 1 \\
B 2 \\
C 3 \\
D 4 \\
E \\ 
F 
$$

Moving around the numbers (people) to match all letters (items) in all ways would take forever, is there any method to do this rigorously? I am not quite sure but I think stirling numbers could somehow be applied.

Comment: Does each person need to be given an item?

Comment: No. It is not required.

Comment: Stirling numbers of the second kind might have been useful if it were the *items* which were different but the people identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_1$ be the number of items received by the first person, $x_2$ the number of items received by the second person, etc...

We are then asking how many non-negative integer solutions exist to the system

$$\begin{cases}x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=6\\x_i\geq 0\end{cases}$$

or if every person must get at least one item, how many strictly positive integer solutions exist to the problem.

These are both very standard problems.  The usual approach being to use a technique called [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) which will in this situation result in a total count of the number of outcomes as being

$$\binom{6+4-1}{4-1} = \binom{9}{3}$$